# Passing and returning variables in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass variables from one function to another.

Like for example:

FuncA: takes in 3 inputs from the user and I want to use those 3 inputs in FuncB.

How would I do that? Would I just return the 3 values from FuncA and just pass it in as parameter of Func B?

Would I do something like this?
**Without using pointers.

```
int FuncA(void);
int FuncB(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E);

int main(void)
{
    FuncA(void);
    FuncB(A,B,C);
}

int FuncA(void)
{
    printf("Enter 3 number:");
    scanf("%d %d %d" &A, &B, &C);
    return A, B, C;
}

int FuncB(int A, int B, int C)
{
    .............
}
```

Comment: `return A,B,C;` will only return `C` value. Left hand operand of comma expressions has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you can only `return` one value per function. This will probably make you ask, "how is it possible to get the values for A, B, and C from FuncA?"

How much do you know about pointers? The solution will be difficult to understand if you do not have a firm grip of what pointers are and how they work.

The solution is to pass 3 pointers (one for A, B, and C) so that FuncA can assign a value to them. This doesn't use the `return` keyword. It's assigning values  at a specific location in memory which is, A, B, and C.

```
int FuncA(int* A, int* B, int* C)
{
    printf("Enter 3 number:");
    scanf("%d %d %d", A, B, C);
}
```

Now that A, B, and C contain the user input, we can pass those values to FuncB. You final code should look like this:

```
int FuncA(int* A, int* B, int *C);
int FuncB(int A, int B, int C);

int main(void)
{
    int A;
    int B;
    int C;

    FuncA(&A, &B, &C);
    FuncB(A, B, C);
}

int FuncA(int* A, int* B, int* C)
{
    printf("Enter 3 number:");
    scanf("%d %d %d", A, B, C);
}

int FuncB(int A, int B, int C)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The question seems to request a solution that does not use pointers.

Answer (score 5):

One approach:

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} ABC;

ABC funcA(void);
{
    ABC abc;
    printf("Enter 3 numbers: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d %d %d", &abc.a, &abc.b, &abc.c);
    return abc;
}

void funcB1(ABC abc)
{
    ...
}

void funcB2(int a, int b, int c)
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    funcB1(funcA());  // one alternative

    ABC result = funcA();  // another alternative
    funcB2(result.a, result.b, result.c);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would setup your system like this:

```
void FuncA(int *A, int *B, int *C);
int FuncB(int A, int B, int C);

int main(void)
{
  // Declare your variables here
  int A, B, C;
  // Pass the addresses of the above variables to FuncA
  FuncA(&A, &B, &C);
  // Pass the values to FuncB
  FuncB(A, B, C);
}

void FuncA(int *A, int *B, int *C)
{ 
  printf("Enter 3 numbers: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%d %d %d", A, B, C);
}

int FuncB(int A, int B, int C)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FuncA is returning an int. Assuming you want to call FuncB with A,B,C parametersa and return to the caller of FuncA whatever FuncB returns, you want something like this.

```
int FuncA(void)
{ 
printf("Enter 3 number:");
scanf("%d %d %d" &A, &B, &C);
return FuncB(A, B, C);
}
```

Comment: would I still return FuncB(A,B,C) if FuncB had previous parameter withint it ?

Answer (score -3):

Declare A, B and C as global variables:

```
int A, B, C;
int FuncA(void);
int FuncB(int A, int B, int C);
....
```

and access them from any function, whether parameters or not.  Or declare them static globals to limit the possible damage of global scoping.

Comment: Global variables are considered bad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad.

Comment: Question was closed, as whether global variables are good or bad is merely a matter of opinion and context.  For instance their use may compile to less code on a system with 2k of memory or less.